# Adding js and css files for many pages, but not for all

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Currently I have a single layout file. But now I need to add some `css` and `js` files to many of the pages, yet not all.

I don't want to manually go to each page and @push the files to the styles/scripts stacks.

One of the ways I could do it is passing condition to the layout file:

```
@extends('layouts.master', ['more_assets' => true])
```

and

```
 // layouts/master.blade.php
@if ($extraAssets)
    <link rel="stylesheet" ...>
    <script src="..."></script>
@endif
```

But is there a better way to do it? Maybe extending the master layout into a secondary layout and include the files there, then on the relevant pages, extend the secondary layout?

The problem with that is, I don't think I can inherit sections from the grandparent layout:

```
// layouts/master.blade.php
<html>
<head>
    <meta ...>
    <meta ...>
    <meta ...>
    
    <title> some title </title>

    <link href=" ... " rel="stylesheet">
    <link href=" ... " rel="stylesheet">
    <link href=" ... " rel="stylesheet">
    <link href=" ... " rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

    <main>
        @yield('content')
    </main>
   
    <script src=" ... "></script>
    <script src=" ... " ></script>
    <script src=" ... " ></script>
    <script src=" ... "></script>

    @stack('scripts')
</body>
</html>
```

the secondary layout:

```
   // layouts/secondary.blade.php
    @extends('master')
    
    @push('styles')
        // push styles here
    @endpush
    
    @push('scripts')
        // push scripts here
    @endpush
```

Then I don't think it can work:

```
@extends('secondary')

@section('content')
    // some content
@endsection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it like this

the secondary layout:

@extends('master')

```
@push('styles')
    // push styles here
@endpush
@section('content')
@yield('content')
@ensection

@push('scripts')
    // push scripts here
@endpush
```

Comment: That's actually very neat, now I wonder if that's a good idea to use it or the other one I suggested at the post. In terms of maintenance, better practices etc..

Comment: Update: I just checked again, and it even inherits from the master without needing to yield another content in the `child` layout

Answer (score 0):

you can use laravel blade directive @stack on your master blade

```
//on master
@stack('custom-scripts')

//on extended master blade
@push('custom-scripts)
<scripts> </scripts>
@endpush
```